# Is there a Unicode Character for a cylinder database?

Tags: unicode

I am looking for a single symbol/letter to represent a data source in text of an HTML page (or Markdown).

I would like to use the cylinder shape has usual for a database.

Maybe I am not searching for the right word, but I am not figuring out any Unicode for a cylinder or something similar.

Is there a Unicode Character for a cylinder?

Answer (score 8):

There’s U+26C1 WHITE DRAUGHTS KING ⛁ and U+26C3 BLACK DRAUGHTS KING ⛃, which are similar visually if not semantically.

Answer (score 6):

I tend to (mis)use  (Oil drum) \x1F6E2, since I have more databases than oil drums. (See [Unicode.org](https://util.unicode.org/UnicodeJsps/list-unicodeset.jsp?a=%5B:Lowercase_Mapping=%F0%9F%9B%A2:%5D) )

Answer (score 4):

You can also use a square shape to represent a database (looks like a server farm):

▤ Square with Horizontal Fill ([U+25A4](https://unicode-table.com/en/25A4/))

⌸ Apl Functional Symbol Quad Equal ([U+2338](https://unicode-table.com/en/2338/))

Answer (score 2):

There's a file cabinet U+1F5C4. 
And a card file box and card file index.